# Convert function-quoted form #'... to string

Tags: functions, string, symbol-function

I have tried `(symbol-name x)`, but it doesn't work if the argument is a lambda:

- ok:

`#'execute-extended-command`

- not ok:

```
#'(lambda (&optional frame) (interactive) (message "hi 8"))
```

Comment: That's why a lambda definition is called an "anonymous" function, What are you *really* trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you need this, but one way is:

```
(format "%s" #'(lambda () (interactive)))
```

⇒

```
"(closure (t) nil (interactive))"
```